# Use argument of unrun command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

If I wanted to run `mv arg1 $(sed arg1 's/regex/replace/')` is there a better way to to do it than to reinsert the filename into the sed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `rename`

If you have the perl utility `rename` installed, then use:

```
rename 's/regex/replace/' arg1
```

For your convenience, `arg1` can be a glob.

On debian-like systems, the perl `rename` is installed as part of the `perl` package.  Beware, however, that there are some linux systems that have installed a different and incompatible utility, part of `util-linux`.

#### Using `bash`

`bash` has a pattern substutition facility that can be used to rename files:

```
f=arg1; mv "$f" "${f//pattern/replace}"
```

Note that `pattern` is a shell glob, not a regex.

Comment: I have the `util-linux` version installed. I'll check if perl-rename is in the Fedora or RPMFusion repos.